# Adding content through HTML attributes

Tags: html, css

If i have HTML code:

```
<center></center>
```

But i want it to look like this:

```
<center>Hello, world!</center>
```

However I do not want to code it like that, instead i want to do something like:

```
<center value="Hello, world!"></center>
```

How would i do this?

Also, could I use this attribute for all HTML tags?  Such as:

```
<p></p>
<h1></h1>
<li></li>
```

ect...

Comment: Why on earth would you want that? Is it really worth adding the content to some attribute and then bother adding it as real content? Why not do it the normal way from the beginning?

Comment: Why don't you want to write it like it should be written

Comment: This is more of a CSS question, so that I can add default content to tags via CSS.

Comment: So for example: If i create a table that is blank, i can go into CSS and add default content to each table item such as "THIS SLOT IS BLANK" or something of the likes.

Comment: @SLaks Doesnt [:empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) do?

Comment: @SLaks It's do-able... `element:after { content: attr(value); }` although the premise of the question is unclear.

Comment: Since we're talking CSS, stop using `<center>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["So for example: If i create a table that is blank, i can go into CSS and add default content to each table item such as "THIS SLOT IS BLANK" or something of the likes."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23875357/1256925#comment36751244_23875357) - this is possible:

```
table td:empty::before {
    content: "Empty cell";
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ahaWZ/). That fills in the text `Empty cell` in all empty table cells.

This does have its limitations though. For example, you won't be able to perform the normal actions on the CSS-generated content (like selecting, copying, etc.), and the `:empty` pseudo-class is [not supported in IE8 and lower](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty#Browser_compatibility).

If you want to insert an attribute's value as text, you can do that via the same `content` rule:

```
table td:empty::before {
    content: attr(data-value);
}
```

I used the `data-value` attribute there, because `td` elements don't have a HTML attribute called `value`. That would look [**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/ahaWZ/1/)